# Why does my mesh move when i add an avatar?

Tags: unity, animation, importing

I've imported a wall model into my scene, it snaps to the other walls fine until I add an avatar to the model to animate it, then it moves.

here's some picture to explain:

The first picture in the scene:

[image]

This picture is in the game:

[image]